# System.ImageList.hpp ファイルはどのような機能を持つコンポーネントですか？

Tags: c++

＊同じ質問をStack teratailにも投稿しています。
https://teratail.com/questions/336788

古いプロジェクトファイルに機能を追加したいため、C++Builder2009をWindows10にインストールしました。
追加するコンポーネントは、プロジェクト内の「component」というフォルダ一覧を全てインストールするのですが、Windows10では、いくつかインストールエラーになり、それぞれ最新版をダウンロードしてきましたが、同様のエラーになり、セットアップできませんでした。

そこで、当時の開発環境と同様な構成を考え、仮想環境のWindowsXpにインストールしました。
追加するコンポーネントも全てインストールでき、環境設定でライブラリパスも指定しました。
この状態で、プロジェクトの読み込みにエラーはでませんでしたが、ビルドすると、次のカ所にエラーがでました。

```
#include <System.ImageList.hpp>
```

このエラーの、 <System.ImageList.hpp>というファイルは、検索しても出てきませんでした。

まだ、追加するコンポーネントが必要だと考えられますが、この<System.ImageList.hpp>というファイルは、
どのような機能を持つコンポーネントですか？
また、入手先が分かればおしらせください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

エラーとなっているファイルに含まれるのは、TImageListという同じサイズの画像のコレクションを管理するコンポーネントです。
バージョンは異なりますのでファイル名が変わっていますが、公式のヘルプは以下になります。

[Vcl.Controls.TImageList - RAD Studio API Documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/ja/Vcl.Controls.TImageList)

これは標準でインストールされる物だったと思うので、インストールが上手くいっていないのか、ライブラリパス等がちゃんと設定されていない状態なのでは無いかと思います。

---

以下追記
調べて見た所、C++Builder2009には、アップデートが4つリリースされているようです。
現在、登録ユーザーがダウンロード出来るISOイメージは上記アップデートが適用された物となっているようですが、購入時のDVD等からインストールしている場合はもしかするとアップデートが適用されていないのかもしれません。アップデートが未適用の場合、アップデートで直るかもしれません。

ページ内のリンクが切れていて修正リスト等の確認は出来ませんがアップデートのダウンロードは可能なようです。
リリースノートへのリンクは下記です。

[Delphi and C++Builder 2009 Update 1 リリースノート](https://edn.embarcadero.com/jp/article/38872/)
[リリースノート： Delphi 2009 および C++Builder 2009 Update 2](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39109)
[リリース ノート： Delphi 2009 および C++Builder 2009 Update 3、Update 4](https://edn.embarcadero.com/article/39592)

アップデートのダウンロードページへのリンクは下記です。
ダウンロードについては、製品ユーザーとしての登録が無いとダウンロード不可かもしれません。

[Update 1 for RAD Studio 2009, Delphi 2009 and C++Builder 2009](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26206)
[Update 2 for RAD Studio 2009, Delphi 2009, and C++Builder 2009](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26310)
[RAD Studio 2009 Update 3, Update 4 & Boost Update](https://cc.embarcadero.com/Item/26921)

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。勉強不足なので、うまくいかないのですが、パスの設定に誤りはないようなので、再セットアップや別PCへのインストールで試してみます。